# Resources seem not to be copied to iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, resources, ios-simulator

I've created a prototype app which uploads a bunch of photos to a webserver. Everything works fine in the simulator. But when I want to try it on an actual device it does not find the images. I've included them under the resources group in Xcode. Anyone?

Best
–f

Comment: Did you tried to clean the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the filenames. The filesystem on your mac is most likely not case-sensitive, but the filesystem on the actual device is case-sensitive. So make sure the filenames match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project with Build->Clean all Targets, and manually remove the app from the device. Then try building again.

Comment: I've already tried that. That doesn't fix it. I've also tried it on several devices: iPhone 4, 3G and iPod.

Comment: Didn't help me too, does somebody know how to fix it?